# Vue @change event not working in <b-form-datepicker/>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am making a website that has a select form and datepicker form that sends an API request for data. I want to the update the data on every change of these forms, then a "submit" button is not required.

The select works perfectly by using the "@change", but this does not have any effect on the datepicker.

The template is.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">
            <b-form-select v-model="region"
                           :options="regions"
                           class="select_box"
                           @change="get_data()"
            />
            <b-form-datepicker id="first_day_datepicker"
                               v-model="first_day"
                               :min="min_day"
                               :max="max_day"
                               class="mb-2"
                               @change="get_data()"
            />
            <b-form-datepicker id="last_day_datepicker"
                               v-model="last_day"
                               :min="min_day"
                               :max="max_day"
                               class="mb-2"
                               @on-change="get_data()"
            />
</div>
```

And the funtcion looks like this(simplified for example)

```js
methods: {
        get_data() {
            console.log("Change data")
        },
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<b-form-datepicker>` control has no `change` event in its [event list](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#comp-ref-b-form-datepicker-events).

But it does have an `input` event which gets emitted when updating `v-model`:

```html
<b-form-datepicker id="first_day_datepicker"
  v-model="first_day"
  :min="min_day"
  :max="max_day"
  class="mb-2"
  @input="get_data()"
/>
<b-form-datepicker id="last_day_datepicker"
  v-model="last_day"
  :min="min_day"
  :max="max_day"
  class="mb-2"
  @input="get_data()"
/>
```